# Stylesheet issues within ASPX page that has Jquery

Tags: asp.net, css, formatting, stylesheet, jquery-slider

There is an ASPX page with code-behind and it has stylesheet/Jquery used in it.

I do not know much about stylesheet or Jquery but I need to debug this page as the border is not shown fully when page is rendered.

Within stylesheet there is this code and it says 'left bottom no repeat'.

```
#variantslider .slides_container
{
    width: 350px;
    display: none;

    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url('bg_slider_box.png') left bottom no-repeat;

    padding-left: 15px;
    height: 55px;

     }
```

I donot know what do I need to do to get full border. I do not how to debug this page to check if there is anything that is stopping in getting full border.

Currently the output is something below which has left bottom border. Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want rounded borders like the bottom-left border?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev : Yes I want complete rounded border. Please suggest

Comment: IDK what impact will be without seeing more styles, but could you just replace the background with css rounded corners? Like http://jsfiddle.net/92yZB/ of course this won't be rounded in older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently is not found the `bg_slider_box.png` in this line

```
background: url('bg_slider_box.png') left bottom no-repeat;
```

See where is located on your disk, and give the correct url, eg something like

```
background: url('/images/bg_slider_box.png') left bottom no-repeat;
```

Comment: bg_slider_box.png is located in the same folder as stylesheet.css which is located in app_themes folder. I have also checked how this png looks in windows folder and it is exactly same as what I shown in snapshot in my original post.          Please suggest.